# Does 1.5 belong in here?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Today I got a little exercise:
I have 3 intervals, need to make union of them (English is not my first language sorry), and here they are:
$$[1,3) \cup (1,2] \cup [-10,-2]$$

When I am asked does $1.5$ belong in this interval, I said: "Yes, it belongs".
I assumed that interval is: $[-10,3)$. $-10$ is less than $1.5$ and $1.5$ is less than $3$, right?

Where did I make a mistake ? (the answer is "no").
And one more thing: It's not 100% sure that I made mistake, it might belong but I somehow made a mistake.

Comment: Is $(2,1]$ a mistake? Or are you interpreting it as $\emptyset$? Either way, $1.5$ is definitely in the interval $[1,3)$ so it should be in the union.

Comment: perfect English in my opinion

Comment: It's mistake. It was meant to be 1,2, not 2,1.

Comment: Your reasoning is perfectly fine. If you have the proof of something, then there is no reason to doubt yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these intervals contain real numbers, 1.5 is included in the union. We have that $1<1.5<3$, so 1.5 is contained in the interval $[1,3)$, which is included in the union. You can check that this is sensible by recalling the definition of an interval $[a,b)=\{x\in A\mid a\leq x<b\}$ for whatever set $A$ you are working with, in this case most likely $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

$1.5$ is contained in $[1,3)$ and hence also in that union, even though I don't know what is meant by $(2,1]$...

Comment: It's mistake, it was meant to be 1,2, not 2,1. I am sorry.

Comment: The answer stands, $1.5$ is contained without a doubt.